# Please help me find the solution, this error is accruing after imported the stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, stack-navigator

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\Kisansetu\example\example\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\Kisansetu\example\example\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\Kisansetu\example\example\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Naveen\Desktop\Kisansetu\example\example\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, see how do I ask a good question [ask].

Comment: Please share react native version and react-native-screens version in your app.